# Rails Feed Parsing Model and Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rss

goddesses and demi-gods of StackOverflow,

I have been trying to figure out this little problem for 1 week, 3 days, 17 hours, 19 minutes and 59 potatoes.

I am new to Rails and I'm trying to create an app that takes in multiple RSS Feeds. I need each feed to belong to the respective News Outlet it came from. How can I do this while also populating the Feed Entries database?

Here is what I've gotten up to...

FeedEntry model

```
class FeedEntry < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :news_outlet
    def self.update_from_feed(feed_url)
        feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_url)
        feed.entries.each do |entry|
            unless exists? :guid => entry.id
                create!(
                    :name           => entry.title,
                    :summary        => entry.summary,
                    :url            => entry.url,
                    :published_at   => entry.published,
                    :guid           => entry.id

                )
            end
        end
    end
end
```

NewsOutlet Model

```
 class NewsOutlet < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :feed_entries
end
```

NewsOutlet Controller

```
class NewsOutletsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_filter :verify_is_admin, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @news_outlets = NewsOutlet.all
  end

  def new
    @news_outlet = NewsOutlet.new
  end

  def create
    @news_outlet = NewsOutlet.new(news_outlet_params)

    @news_outlet.save
    redirect_to @news_outlet
  end

  def show
    @news_outlet = NewsOutlet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @news_outlet = NewsOutlet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @news_outlet = NewsOutlet.find(params[:id])
    if @news_outlet.update news_outlet_params
      redirect_to @news_outlet
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def delete
  end

  def destroy
    @news_outlet = NewsOutlet.find(params[:id])
    @news_outlet.destroy
    redirect_to news_outlets_path
  end  

  private

  def news_outlet_params
    params.require(:news_outlet).permit(:name, :url)
  end
end
```

And my NewsOutlet#Index just in case, which is where I'd like to call upon the FeedEntry DB to populate it with the news headlines.

```
<h1>Blah</h1>   
 <% if @news_outlets.present? %>
        <% @news_outlets.each do |news_outlet| %>
            <% entries = FeedEntry.update_from_feed(news_outlet.url) %>
            <p><%= link_to "#{news_outlet.name}", news_outlet.url %></p>

            <% entries.first(5).each do |entry| %>
                <%= link_to "#{entry.title}", entry.url %><br>
            <% end %>
            <p><%= link_to "Show", news_outlet_path(news_outlet) %></p>
            <hr>
        <% end %>
    <% else %>
        <p>No news outlets yet...</p>
    <% end %>
```

May you have many potatoes in the apocalypse. Any help is much appreciated <3

Comment: This is what FeedEntry looks like: FeedEntry(id: integer, name: string, summary: text, url: string, published_at: datetime, guid: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, news_outlet_id: integer)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test it myself but I think this should work:

NewsOutlet Model

```
class NewsOutlet < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :feed_entries

  def update_from_feed
    entries = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse(self.url)

    entries.each do |entry|
      feed_entries.where(guid: entry.id).first_or_create! do |fe|
        fe.name = entry.title
        fe.summary = entry.summary
        fe.url = entry.url
        fe.published_at = entry.published
      end
    end

    entries.first(5)
  end

end
```

FeedEntry model

```
class FeedEntry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :news_outlet
end
```

View

```
<% @news_outlets.each do |news_outlet| %>
  <p><%= link_to "#{news_outlet.name}", news_outlet.url %></p>
  <% news_outlet.update_from_feed.each do |entry| %>
    <%= link_to "#{entry.title}", entry.url %><br>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= link_to "Show", news_outlet_path(news_outlet) %></p>
  <hr>
<% end %>
```